# Symfony2 JMS Serializer JSON_ constant error

Tags: php, json, symfony, jms, serialization

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'JMS\Serializer\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message
>   'Expected either an integer representing one of the JSON_ constants,
>   or a string of the constant itself.' in
>   /var/www/mobilegolfplan.com/vendor/jms/serializer-bundle/JMS/SerializerBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php:142\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 [internal function]:
>   JMS\SerializerBundle\DependencyInjection\{closure}(Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/mobilegolfplan.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ExprBuilder.php(229):
>   call_user_func(Object(Closure), Array)\n#2
>   /var/www/mobilegolfplan.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php(254):
>   Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\{closure}(Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/mobilegolfplan.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php(308):
>   Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\BaseNode->normalize(Array)\n#4
>   /var/www/mobilegolfplan.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode
>   in
>   /var/www/mobilegolfplan.com/vendor/jms/serializer-bundle/JMS/SerializerBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
>   on line 142

I tried install a project in production server and i got error. PHP json extension installed and enabled. If i want try composer install, i was seeing that error , again, again and again.

How i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON Constants in the config file try to give 0 like this:

```
jms_serializer:
    visitors:
        json:
            options: 0
```

You might not be using the correct version of PHP. Are you using PHP 5.3 or less?

For the Json constants: `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to work, you must use PHP 5.4 or higher.

In PHP 5.4 or more the below code will work:

```
jms_serializer:
    visitors:
        json:
            options:   [ JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES , JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ]
```